# Passing std::string reference from std::stringstream as parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, reference

I am using std::stringstream to construct a string and then attempting to pass the completed string as a reference to a function which takes as a parameter a std::string&.

I am getting a compilation error on GCC:

```
../src/so.cpp:22:21: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
../src/so.cpp:12:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void myFunc(std::string&)’
make: *** [src/so.o] Error 1
```

The same code is compiling on Windows VS2012, but fails on my Linux and Android builds. What is the reason for this?

I can work around the issue by temporarily assigning ss.str() to a temporary std::string and then passing that string by reference, but this seems slightly silly. What is the correct way to do this cleanly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void myFunc (std::string& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}

int main (void)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "this is a test";

    myFunc (ss.str());              // Fails

    std::string s = ss.str();
    myFunc (s);                     // Pass

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set the warning level to `/W4` and VS will tell you a non-standard extension is being used at that line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that `myFunc` takes a non-const lvalue reference. `stringstream::str()` returns a string by value. You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference in standard C++, but VS has an "extension" that allows this. That is the reason it compiles on VS and not on other compilers.

`const` lvalue references, on the other hand, can bind to rvalues. So modifying your function thus would make it work:

```
void myFunc (const std::string &msg) { /* as before */ }
```

Comment: Did the trick nicely thanks; makes sense. Thanks for the other answers too, however I found this one the most informative.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
void myFunc (std::string& msg)
```

to this:

```
void myFunc (const std::string& msg)
//           ^^^^^ this will allow temporaries like ss.str()
```

There are versions of Visual Studio that will *foolishly* allow a temporary to bind to a non-const reference.  It is **dangerous and not valid C++**, however.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not writing to the string inside `myFunc`, accept a const reference:

```
void myFunc (std::string const &msg)
{
  std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Those can be bound to temporary objects

Answer (score -1):

So the reason that you are having this error, is that ss.str() returns a const string, not a string. 
By creating a new string you are creating a non-const variable that is set to the same value as ss.str() and thus can be passed into myFunc().
Making a new string as you have it is probably the easiest way to fix this and still use the function as is.

Comment: But `ss.str()` doesn't return a const string.